# C++ Reverse Polish Notation Stack

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class, stack

I am working on a project which requires me to accept a string written in reverse polish notation and evaluate it using a stack.  I am supposed to go through the string and if the element is a number, I keep going through the string until I reach a space, and I convert that section of the string to an integer using atoi.  I then push that integer onto the stack.  My code for this works, however, I am not sure how to continue to the next number after the space.  This is the for loop I have so far:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    int b;
    char c[a.size()];
    while (isdigit(a[i]))
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
        c[i] = a[i];
        b = atoi(c);
        i++;
    }
    cout << b << endl;
    stack.push(b);
}
```

This always pushes the first integer onto the stack, even if there are more after a space.  What would I need to add to continue pushing integers onto the stack after a space?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you post all the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
c[i] = a[i];
```

When reading the second integer you will use the current `i` and not write the digits at the start of your array `c`. The call to `atoi(c)` will see the first integer which was not overwriten and return that value.

You should use a second index to put digits in the `c` array and reset this second index after you pushed an integer on the stack.

Here is an example (not tested):

```
unsigned j = 0;
char c[a.size()+1];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    int b;
    while (isdigit(a[i]))
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
        c[j] = a[i];
        j++;
        i++;
    }
    c[i] = '\0';
    b = atoi(c);
    cout << b << endl;
    stack.push(b);
    j = 0;
}
```

I assume this is some homework and you must work the way you do. In idiomatic **C++** one would use a [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) for this work.

```
#include <sstream>

int b;
std::stringstream buffer(a);
while(buffer >> b) {
    stack.push(b);
}
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  Thanks for your help!